# newbie: holoviews Curves from pandas dataset columns

Tags: holoviews

I have a pandas dataframe with columns labeled...

```
x
y
true_x
true_y
```

I would like to plot a curve of `true_x` vs `true_y` overlaid with
points `y` vs `x`.

The tutorials leave me baffled since they only describe simple 2D and 3D examples.

Answer (score 1):

We're about to start working extensively on additional documentation so that's good feedback. To create a simple plot like that simply declare a `Curve` and a `Scatter` object each with the appropriate `kdims` and `vdims` and overlay them using the `mul` operator:

```py
curve = hv.Curve(df, kdims=['true_x'], vdims=['true_y'])
scatter = hv.Scatter(df, kdims=['x'], vdims=['y'])
curve * scatter
```

Comment: so there is no holoviews Table or other element to import the dataframe into?

Comment: So here is what I ended up with for a Kalman filter example
where data contains the measurements,  truth and Kalman estimates:

%%opts Scatter [width=600,height=300]
data['Time']=np.linspace(start=0, stop=len(data)-1,num=len(data))

print(data.info())

hv.Curve  (data, kdims=['x.true'], vdims=['y.true']) *\
hv.Scatter(data, kdims=['x.meas'], vdims=['y.meas'])(style=dict(color='r')) *\
hv.Scatter(data, kdims=['x.est'], vdims=['y.est'])(style=dict(color='darkgreen')) *\
hv.Curve  (data, kdims=['x.est'], vdims=['y.est'])(style=dict(color='lightgreen'))

Comment: and I need to figure out how to remove a badly formated comment.  Sorry!